# Odds of guessing 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 out of 10 card suits

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have deck of cards on a table, and I try to guess 10 times in a row the suit of the top card, removing each card after I guess. What are the odds that I will be right only once, twice, thrice... up to all ten times?

Also, does it change the probabilities if I don't look at the cards until after all 10 guesses are made? That is, I keep them turned over and just log my guesses so I can check if I was right after all 10 guesses are made. If it does alter the probabilities, how does it do so?

I'm no mathematician, so if there's a simple formula for calculating how likely 1 correct, 2 correct... 10 correct is, I'd love to know it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this an ordinary deck of cards?  If so, then looking at the cards as you go clearly changes the odds.  If, say, you see nine spades in a row, the probability that the next is also a spade is quite low.

Comment: Yes it's an ordinary deck of cards @lulu

Comment: Okay, so assuming you don't look at the cards, how do I calculate the odds of getting 1,2,3...10 correct guesses? Thanks! @lulu

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand anything on that page lol. I did find an online calculator that makes it easy to do though. Thanks!

Comment: @lulu I wouldn't say it is just a binomial distribution, mainly as you remove the top card every time thus changing the odds every time regardless if you look at the cards or not, but also because I would like to have some clarification for the guessing process. Does one stick to one suit or can you change your mind every time? For bot models I expect a messy calculation

Comment: @Hirshy  Yes, you're right.  The guesses are not independent, I'll delete those comments.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @lulu, I looked up an online calculator that does binomial distributions and lets me input the number of trials and the probability for each trial to yield the result.

Comment: On reflection, this depends on your guessing scheme.  I was assuming that you were guessing uniformly  at random each time.  In that case the guesses are correct (or not) independent of any other guess.   If you use some other scheme, this may not be the case.  If, say, you guess spades all the time, and you had $14$ trials instead of $10$, then there would be no chance of getting them all right.  Guessing uniformly at random, you  can still use the normal distribution.

Comment: That makes sense. In the test I'm doing it's mostly blind trials, so using the calculator is the way to go for me.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify an earlier discussion in the comments (now partially deleted):

Assume you are guessing blindly, without seeing the cards as you go.

This clearly depends on the guessing scheme. To illustrate this, suppose you had $14$ trials and that you guessed spades every time.  Then there is no chance of guessing them all correctly.

However, if you assume that you guess uniformly at random, then your chance of guessing correctly is $\frac 14$ each time, independent of all the other guesses. Thus, under this assumption, the binomial distribution applies and the probability that you guess exactly $n$ correct out of $10$ is $$\binom {10}n\times \left(\frac 14\right)^n\times \left(\frac 34\right)^{10-n}$$

This, of course, raises the question "is there a better way to guess"?  This will, in part, depend on what you mean by better.  All strategies have the same mean, $\frac {10}4$, so saying that a strategy is "better" than another requires you to specify some utility function.

If you are seeing the cards as you go, then of course you can do better.  I assume that the optimal strategy (as to mean) is to uniformly select from the most probable suits.  Thus, if the first card is a spade, you should guess equally amongst hearts, diamonds, clubs, for the second.  I have not calculated the expected result of that strategy.  At first glance, it depends on the path you take (i.e. on the suits for the prior cards). That suggests a perfectly good computation, but one that would need to be done with a machine.

To see what the calculation would look like, let's do it for $2$ trials, instead of $10$.  In that case, the first guess has a mean of $\frac 14$ but the second guess, using the scheme I mentioned, will be correct with probability $\frac {39}{51}\times \frac 13=\frac {13}{51}>\frac 14$ since you need, first, for the card to be a different suit than the first and then you need to guess it correctly.  Thus the mean in that case is $$\frac 14+\frac {13}{51}\approx .5049$$ which, as expected, is at least slightly better than blind guessing.